# Initialising a function with default values result in additional undefined log

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, console.log

```
function addNums(num1 = 1, num2 = 2) {
  console.log(num1 + num2);
}
console.log(addNums());
```

This code results in an output of:

 **3** 
 **undefined**

Where is the undefined coming from?

Comment: Your `addNums` has no `return` statement, which means it implicitly returns `undefinedd` so you log *that* from `console.log(addNums())`

Comment: Remove the last console.log(addNums()) because it will print the return value of the function (the functions return undefined by default)

Comment: Long story short, you have 2x `console.log()` in your code, so it will log two values.

Answer (score 1):

addNums does not return any explicit values, so is implicitly returning undefined, which is being printed on the 2nd console.log statement.